# What back up options exist for NES cartridges?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, nes

My beloved NES cartridges are getting pretty old, and recently some of them have been functioning sporadically.

Do you know of other backup alternatives other than [RetroZone's PowerPak](http://www.retrousb.com/product_info.php?cPath=24&products_id=34)? It's pretty expensive.

Is it the only alternative?

Comment: I deleted two answers to this question that suggested downloading ROMS: http://www.nintendo.com/corp/legal.jsp#roms -- "Therefore, whether you have an authentic game or not, or whether you have possession of a Nintendo ROM for a limited amount of time, i.e. 24 hours, it is illegal to download and play a Nintendo ROM from the Internet."

Comment: To clarify, it is only legal if you make the backups yourself (eg RetroZone's PowerPak)

Comment: @JuanManuelFormoso: Simply because Nintendo says something doesn't necessarily make it true, even if it's about their IP.  Their self-serving interpretation of the law is full of crap, according to plenty of other interpretations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another strategy would be to find copies of the cartridge.

Try looking in local pawnshops.  They usually have lots of old cartridges for next to nothing.  You might have to look for awhile if you're looking for specific games.

You can also ask at a GameStop if they have any suggestions for where to look.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://home.clara.net/robwebb/backup/) site lists a bunch of backup devices, but there doesn't seem to be any listed for the NES.  I don't know if the SNES devices will work for the NES.